# Are there any symbol to make a "half-space" in MathJax? half the size of $\text{\,}$ approx $\text{\kern 0.08333em}$?

Tags: support, mathjax, formatting, font, typesetting

Are there any symbol to make a half-space in MathJax? half the size of $\text{\,}$ approx  $\text{\kern 0.08333em}$ ?

If I write jointly the letter $\rho$ with the "letter C with undertext letter D" $C_D$, and then the letters $A$ and letter $v$ (as for the formula of the [Drag force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)#The_Drag_Equation)), the result is $\rho C_D A v$ where the letter D ends being too far from the letter C compared with the position of $\rho$, as it where one different symbol $\rho C$ instead.

To separate them I introduced a space with $\text{\,}$ ending in $\rho \,C_D A v$, but due the proximity between letters $A$ and $v$ now looks like $\rho$ is a little far away, so I have the doubt if there exist a "half-space" symbol but I didn't found anything yet that do the trick.

I tried also with $\text{\;\!}$ with the following result $\rho \;\!C_D Av$ which looks better, but following what is said [here](https://es.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Spacing_in_math_mode):

> $\begin{array}{l}
> \text{\,} = 3\,\text{mu} \\ 
> \text{\:} = 4\,\text{mu} \\
> \text{\;} = 5\,\text{mu} \\
> \text{\!} = -3\,\text{mu} \\
> \Rightarrow \text{\;\!} = 2\,\text{mu} \neq 1.5\,\text{mu}\,\text{(half space \,)}
>  \end{array}$

so is not exactly half-space so maybe there is a symbol through it could be improved.

---

*Added later*

I found later the following:

> $\begin{array}{l}
> \text{\negmedspace} = -4\,\text{mu}\\
> \Rightarrow \text{\;\negmedspace} = 1\,\text{mu} \neq 1.5\,\text{mu}\,\text{(half space \,)}
>  \end{array}$

which also isn't a half-space, but introduce a spacing of $1\,\text{mu}$ so it looks better (similar with the specing between letters $A$ and $v$):
$$\rho \;\negmedspace C_D A v$$

---

*2nd added later*

Following the answer by @PeterPhipps it is possible to define the horizontal spacing at will, for example at half-space through $\text{\hspace{0.08333em}}$, which ends by looking as:
$$\begin{array}{l l}
\text{original - no spacing} & \rho C_D A v \\
\text{standard - \, spacing} & \rho\, C_D A v \\
\text{using \hspace{0.08333em}} & \rho\hspace{0.08333em} C_D A v \\
\text{using \;\negmedspace} & \rho\;\negmedspace C_D A v \\
\text{using \;\!} & \rho\;\! C_D A v \\
\end{array}$$

Looks like all also works on LaTex, but with `\hspace` there is a risk of having your formulas splitted at mid terms if a change of line happened, so instead you should use the following: `\hspace*{0.08333em}`

Comment: @hardmath Thank for commenting. I wasn't able to find a symbol that has half-space to fill it with $\text{\phantom}$. But through the pages I found through this term I found the following: $\text{\;\negmedspace}$ which isn't a half-space, but introduce a spacing of $1\,\text{mu}$ so it looks better $$\rho \;\negmedspace C_D A v$$

Comment: Maybe better asked on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: The simple string "\rho C_D Av" crowds $ρ$ and $C$ close together because MathJax thinks you are spelling out a word with the two letters. One way to persuade it this is not your intention is to put the Greek letter in a separate "environment", e.g. "\operatorname{\rho} C_D Av" gives $\operatorname{\rho} C_D Av$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe `\hspace` is what you require.

For example, `$\rho \hspace{0.08333em}C$` produces $\rho \hspace{0.08333em}C$ as opposed to $\rho C$